# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session.invalid address of the browser start-up failure

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Opening in existing browser session.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: 'DESKTOP-KSCG3R5', ip: '192.168.1.7'
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:561)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:229)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:52)
    at MySeleniumLearning.Pandenm.LaunchWeb.main(LaunchWeb.java:15)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely.
Build info: version: '4.8.3', revision: 'e5e76298c3'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '19.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:234)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    ... 7 more
```

I have tried on chrome and firefox both.but it is not working. Please suggest as I am new to selenium